# Adding multiple dependent Jars using Javafxpackager

Tags: java, jar, javafx

I'm having issues adding multiple packages in the command line.

```
javafxpackager -createjar -outfile outjar -srcdir /dest/to/src -classPath 
libs/library1.jar:libs/library2.jar -appClass pathto.MainClass -v
```

I've tried with spaces and multiple `-classPath` flags and obviously I've tried the colons as well. I'm working in Ubuntu and the program works great in Eclipse, but when I package it, it works until I try to do something that requires an external library. If I use only one I can do that function fine, but need multiples to work fully.

If anyone can shine some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried creating the jar by using the export function in Eclipse?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it works until I try to do something that requires and external library"? Do you mean the `javafxpackager` won't create the jar when you specify third-party libs or do you mean it won't run? What is erroneous output message you get?

Comment: I can create the jar and run it using "java -jar outjar.jar" and the GUI appears and looks fine. Then when I try to do something the references any of the external jars it crashes.    Export jar from eclipse produces a very weird GTK thread and something about a missing link.

Comment: Instead of directly using javafxpackager use the zen-java maven plugin which is easy to use and its internally uses the javafxpackager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
-classPath libs/library1.jar:libs/library2.jar
```

use:

```
-classpath "libs/library1.jar;libs/library2.jar"
```

Whatever it is that parses the `JavaFX-ClassPath` that is created in the manifest by the packager doesn't like you having `:` to separate the libraries.  When you use a `;` instead in the `-classpath` argument, the generated `JavaFX-ClassPath` will use a space to separate the libraries and the runtime will then be able to use both libraries.

Here is a sample manifest I generated using the JavaFX packager on OS X (which worked for me).

```
$ jar xf HelloWorld.jar
$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
JavaFX-Application-Class: HelloWorld
JavaFX-Class-Path: lib/phrases.jar lib/friend.jar
JavaFX-Version: 2.2
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
```

Jar containing the manifest was generated using the command on OS X 10.8 Java 1.8.0-ea-b113:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javafxpackager -createjar -classpath "lib/phrases.jar;lib/friend.jar" -srcdir . -outfile HelloWorld -appclass HelloWorld
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I saw semicolons places but never occurred to wrap it in quotes.  Thank you very much!